# Spring Boot Lazy Loading OrderLine items on Orders GetMapping Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

I have the following getMapping request in OrderController for a simple E-Commerce Spring Boot application to demo MVC.

```
@GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Orders> getAllOrders() {
        return ordersService.getAllOrders();
    }
```

In Postman, I get the response accordingly:

```
[
    {
        "order_date": "2021-04-29T19:55:30.964+00:00",
        "amount": 33.0,
        "status": true,
        "id": 3
    },
...
```

I have a OrderDetailVO (Integer productId, Integer quantity) and OrderVO (orderID, ArrayList OrderDetailList) classes in my Models as well.

**I want to see the products associated with the Order in my get response.
Is there a way to Return OrderVO object and OL object along with the Order object?**

Structure: [image: Proj structure]

Comment: just create a lsit of associated products inside of your Order class like so `List<Product> associatedProducts` and then as u return the list of orders u will see the products inside of json as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapping annotation like @ManyToOne @OneToMany in your entity class to get orderDetails.
Follow along below guide to understand mapping in spring boot:

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many